# How to return Mocha test result?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

How can I return the result of Mocha testing to continue working with this result in code instead of the output to console or browser? Thank you.

Comment: What information do you need exactly?

Comment: Success or fail of current test.

Comment: Hi Dzhen,

Seems you raised two question, I wrote a answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097005/how-in-mocha-test-frunction-with-console-log-statement[link]

Comment: Duplication of [How in Mocha test frunction with console.log statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097005/how-in-mocha-test-frunction-with-console-log-statement)

Comment: Actually no, but I understan the main principle. Thanks.

Comment: Without an example it's hard to tell, but I suspect you need to rethink how you are writing your tests. If the result of one test is affecting another, that is a really bad code smell (for your test, that is).